# RxJs Subject not triggering subscription on production environment but works on development and test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Yesterday my team deployed our angular app to a production server after it has been deployed to test server.

The app works in development mode and test server, but on production server the subjects are not triggering their subscription. The same build that was published to test was published on production, there are no file differences.

Does RxJs request some system setup which I'm not aware of which can cause subjects not to work? I have no idea how to debug this nor what the reason for it not working might be.

Services that subjects are on are singleton, I do unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy block, and it works on test, so I don't think it is an issue in code.

Any help or tip in which direction I should go to discover why it doesn't work is appreciated.

Using angular 6.2.2.

Comment: Knowing the Angular version you're using would be helpful, because Angular has been using RxJS 6 since Angular 6.

Comment: sounds like there is an error inside your service, perhaps in a http call, and this error is being 'eaten up'/hidden. You can try to run `ng serve --prod` and see if you can produce it locally

Comment: Please try running `ng serve` with `prod` configuration locally in development mode.

Comment: I'm using Angular 6.2.2. As mentioned the app works on test server where the app is published the same way it is published on production server, response arrives successfully and it is a success, which I can see if I refresh the page, but the subscription events that refresh the data do not trigger and the page looks like no data was added. Again, this works as intended on test environment where the exactly same build was published.

Comment: @Beca the test server does not use a different configuration/environment file?

Comment: @PierreDuc Only difference is in a single config file where backend url is different.

Comment: Is it possible that the Subject is emitting before it gets subscribed to?

Comment: @WillAlexander As mentioned, the project works, the subscription works with same code base on both development and test (ng build --prod) environments but not on production server (same files as test build, with only difference being backend url). I'm interested if there is some system settings that might cause angular or rxjs package not to work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have managed to solve it a while back but I haven't posted the answer.

The issue was with SQL server read and write nodes having a tiny delay, which meant that after we sent a write to the write node we would trigger a read as soon as we get response back, but the read node didn't have the date updated yet (delay was couple of ms) so we got the same data again, which made us think the subscription didn't fire since we could see the value change in database but not the delay.